# Normalizing data based on row data

Tags: python, pandas, normalization

I have got a pandas df with ID and Month and what I would like to do is to label the ID/Month with a number if it is first appearing in the dataset

```
ID     Month      Number
123    201501     1
123    201502     2
123    201503     3
234    201502     1
234    201503     2
455    201503     1
```

So as you can see the ID `123` is occurring multiple times in the dataset in every single month. Moreover ID `234` only occurs from Month `201502`. What I would like to do is to label the rows with a number when they were activated.

Could you please advise?

---

Not sure what is going wrong but this is the output that I get from the formula that you have provided:

```
ID  Month   Num
12  201510  1
12  201511  17
12  201512  2
12  201601  3
12  201602  4
12  201603  5
12  201604  6
12  201605  7
12  201606  8
12  201607  9
12  201608  10
12  201609  11
12  201610  12
12  201611  13
12  201612  14
12  201701  15
12  201702  16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'Month']).reset_index()
df['num'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount() + 1
print (df)
    ID   Month  Number  num
0  123  201501       1    1
1  123  201502       2    2
2  123  201503       3    3
3  234  201502       1    1
4  234  201503       2    2
5  455  201503       1    1
```

Comment: not sure what is going wrong but I'll share some output